# Loading useState when props changes when useEffect already applies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to update my initial state upon changing in props but it does not work even with useEffect. Here is my following code:
from the picture link, you can see that the initial-state is updated from (p4,p1,p3,p5) to (p4,p1,p3,p2), but useEffect did not fire to change the state so the state remained at (p4,p1,p3,p2). I can't figure out why and have been struggling for hours, can anyone help me?

```js
export default (props) => {
  let toollist = props.getData;
  const inistate = {};

  for (let index in toollist) {
    let stkey = (toollist[index].ttype + toollist[index].toolid)
    inistate[stkey] = [0, 0, 120, 120, false]
  }

  inistate.dragging = false
  inistate.resize = false

  console.log("ini:", inistate)

  const [state, setstate] = useState(inistate)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effected")
    setstate(inistate)
  }, [inistate])

  console.log("state:", state)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaMPu.png)

For (getDerivedStateFromProps/moveup to parent componenet) (For Mr.carlosbf):

```
 export default(props)=>{  
const [state,setstate]=useState({});
const [prevstate,setprevstate]=useState(null);
if (props.ini !== prevstate){
    console.log("changed")
    setstate(props.ini)
    setprevstate(props.ini)
    }
console.log("state:",state)
```

For useMemo ( for MR.HMR):

```
let toollist=props.getData; 
const inistate = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("memoed")
    var inistate = {};
    for (let index in toollist) {
        let stkey = (toollist[index].ttype + toollist[index].toolid)
        inistate[stkey] = [0, 0, 120, 120, false]
    }
    inistate.dragging=false
    inistate.resize=false
    return inistate
}, [toollist])
console.log(inistate)

const[state, setstate]=useState(inistate)

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(1);
    setstate(inistate);
},[inistate]);
```

[For Mr.HMR (second picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kShDo.png)

Comment: Try to set `initState` with the result of a [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) that will depend on `props.getData` then the effect will run every time `props.getData` changes and not every time the component renders.

Comment: Hi Mr.HMR, do you mean something like my edit? When I ran the program the useMemo did fire however somehow the State did not change with Setstate, so it still remains empty. Sorry I am still new to React maybe I am missing something important.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks like you are trying to change the state after receiving props unconditionally which is an anti-pattern. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

You could try to pull this logic up the component tree. Or implement `getDerivedStateFromProps` with hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops.

Comment: sorry I am still quite new to this. Does it mean like what I just newly edited? It did run into the if loop but the setstate didnt seem to fire somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using useMemo correctly, here is an example that uses useMemo to return a value that is used the hook to set state again when inistate changes:

```js
const Component = (props) => {
  const toollist = props.getData;
  const inistate = React.useMemo(() => {
    //do whatever you need to create state here
    return toollist;
  }, [toollist]);
  const [state, setstate] = React.useState(inistate);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setstate(inistate);
  }, [inistate]);

  return (
    <pre>
      state in component:
      {JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}
    </pre>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ counter: 0 });
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setState({ ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 })
        }
      >
        change state
      </button>
      <Component getData={state} />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: HI Mr.HMR, thank you I greatly appreciate your help. It seems like the memo did change the inistate, however, it did not launch useEffect in my program when inistate change for some reason. I am wondering could it have been problem with other parts of program. My way of changing the props.getData is by changing the redux state : change the toolset number =>pull toolset list from redux state on parent component (with modifying using JSON.parse/stringfy) =>update inistate=> update the state. It just seems like everything worked until the update state step and that is what got me stucked..

Comment: @William Can you show me the code you have (update question)?

Comment: this is the updated code for children(upper part)  https://github.com/palmswill/canvaswilliam/blob/master/src/component/screenshow.js

Comment: this is the parent         https://github.com/palmswill/canvaswilliam/blob/master/src/component/mainshow.js

Comment: this is the part where i grab toollist from redux https://github.com/palmswill/canvaswilliam/blob/master/src/component/gettooolload.js

Comment: @William `it did not launch useEffect in my program when inistate change` that is impossible with [this code](https://github.com/palmswill/canvaswilliam/blob/master/src/component/screenshow.js#L6-L25). It should log `memoed` then inistate and then `1` from the effect because the effect will run after the component has rendered, because the effect changes state the component will render again but useMemo isn't called.

Comment: When I try to call a function called getList from a component I get an error: `React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "getList" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` it would only work if I rename it to 'useList' or any function name starting with `use` so react sees it as a custom hook. I wonder how you get that code to run without crashing.

Comment: uhmm that is weird since getlist() is just a function I called from gettoolist.js as  functional component at mainshow.js and no error showed up for me..maybe they change something in the newer React? I just started play around with React like 2 weeks ago maybe they changed some of the things so my random way would work.

Comment: In my log it seems to have ran it differently somewhat...if you see the attached picture at the bottom of my post it ran memoed/1 on first render with ini at p4,1,3,5. Then when i changed the state(separated by yellow part )  it memoed twice and inistate change to p4,1,3,2...